# Best way to record sound on App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, audio

Is it possible to live record sound and save it to the server? Does anyone have any resources that explain how this could be achieved? It seems the standard, flash, does not work.  What are other possible solutions?

Comment: What makes you think that Flash does not work? You can create a [Flash](https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/) / [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/) app that reads from a microphone and send the sound stream to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to record the sound and post it to the blobstore. There are no built in facilities in appengine for recording sound but the blobstore can persist any binary data you want.

Comment: so do i do this with JS? are there any good JS libraries or jQuery scripts that can create the sound file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that. I just do the backend :)

Comment: A quick google of "jquery record sound" returned many promising results